# How to full screen applications in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, eclipse

I must have pressed some keys accidentally or something else and my Eclipse window got in a full screen mode. The title bar of the window and the OS task bar disappeared. Everything else is normal. I can switch between apps using Alt+Tab and get to desktop using Super+D.

I am confused is this a bug or a feature?

Can I replicate this? I kind of love the extra screen space I get in this mode.

This screenshot is not edited. It is the full screen shot showing eclipse without title bar and without Operating System task bar.

[image]

Comment: Try pressing F11. It usually puts things in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, you can get out of full screen with any of this combinations:

- <kbd>F11</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (this is Eclipse exclusive)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

You should test in that order to make your windows back to normal.

*This list is not extensive and could be modified with the time*

Comment: F11 works with any application on Lubuntu.

Comment: @KshitizSharma I was ruling out the possibility of being a per-application shortcut.

Comment: And I was just confirming that your answer works. ;-)